# Sunglasses fogging on cool bright mornings - can I improve airflow?

Tags: modification, glasses

My favourite riding sunglasses are my Bollé [Mamba II](https://www.bolle-safety.com/reference/mampsf) safety sunglasses - they're light and wrap around properly while being by far the most  comfortable ones I've found.  They're also cheap.

There is a downside, which is normally only apparent in winter but was a bit of an issue yesterday morning: they fog easily, especially on the bit I look through using the drops or aero bars.  Yesterday was sunny all day, but I started before it warmed up, so I was out in around 10°C, sweating a little.  It's possible wind chill on the outside was cooling the glasses, as I averaged >30km/h for the hour or two this was a problem, before the day warmed up.  This wasn't about stopping, because I didn't, but when rolling along.  It was better when riding into the sun, but that never lasted long.

I like the way they sit so close to my face, but it means that unlike my less-good cycling-specific glasses there's no airflow behind the lens.

The issue may be what they call "upper protection".  They're a sort of frameless design, but with a little ridge running along the top of the lens, at eyebrow height and touching my face.  It's visible (just) in this photo of them upside down:
[image]

They're getting a little scratched and it's nearly time for a new pair, so it's a  good time to try some experiments.  Is there some way I can increase the airflow behind the lens? Are there designs that do this so I can be inspired?  I don't really want to try a coating, because I'm likely to wipe it off.

Other, looser fitting and less comfortable glasses don't fog up nearly as much (including another Bollé polycarbonate pair, so it's not the material).

Comment: I do have a couple of ideas, but want to see what others think before mentioning them

Comment: Wouldn’t airflow behind the glasses defeat the whole purpose of bicycling glasses?

Comment: @Michael I don't believe  a limited amount would.  They'd still keep dust and direct wind out of my eyes, and they'd certainly still block the sun.  I don't (consistently) wear clear glasses for riding, so the latter is a crucial point.

Comment: People who engage in Paint Ball games  use a product called Cat Crap on their face masks. While the name isn't appealing I have used it and it does work

Comment: @mikes but how much does it need re-applying (e.g. if I wipe sweat/suncream off the inside using my jersey)?

Comment: It used to last several hours of running around in the woods. If the issue is sweat dripping on them also consider a skull cap under your helmet.

Comment: I've actually got some stuff for swimming goggles, which works out of the water but I know that one wipe with a cloth and it's gone.

Comment: Do you wear a cycling cap/casket?  Or does your helmet have a visor/brim/peak/sunshade ?

Comment: @Criggie I don't get on with caps under my helmet - they're too hot in summer and the brim get in my line of sight when I get low.  Similarly the only helmet with a brim is a reserve commuting one for when the better one is still sweaty from the night before

Comment: You can also spit in the glasses https://www.leisurepro.com/blog/scuba-guides/spit-work-defogging-scuba-mask-2/

Comment: The times I've had trouble with fogging glasses was due to my own exhaled warm humid air, so I started "blowing away" the air rather than just exhale. That way most of the warm air does not rise right inside the lens.

Comment: Toothpaste, a small dab on a finger rubbed across the lenses and then wiped of with a good clean cloth, works well on my shaving mirror, I see no reason why this wouldn't work on sunglasses, cost effective also I get about a week out of one application

Comment: @Jahaziel that works in winter, certainly.  At its worst I was breathing pretty hard anyway, so far from passively exhaling for the warm moist air to rise into the glasses.

Comment: @DanK but presumably you don't also have sweat running down your shaving mirror, necessitating a wipe when you stop.    That's the problem with all the coating treatments I've tried or seen suggested

Comment: @mikes I run pretty hot anyway.  When I'm sweating hard the last thing I want is extra insulation on my head, and when I have tried riding with anything under my helmet in summer it's been saturated within a couple of hours, as in  literally squeezing the sweat out of my cap at a cafe stop.

Comment: @Chris H correct no sweat on the mirror, the obvious thing to do would be to move the glasses slightly away from the eyes, this would create an airflow and probably avoid sweat issues also

Comment: @DanK I've just edited the question - I've got a couple of other pairs that sit further away, they're both far less comfortable (as are some I've bought and rejected for cycling) and more prone to sliding down my nose, putting the top edge of the frame in a useful part of my field of view.

Comment: Answer in answers, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some modifications and the first test ride (mainly testing fit) was successful.

I noticed on close examination that the bridge fits my nose almost perfectly (except for a slight asymmetry in me - swimming pool steps are harder than cartilage).  This means little or no airflow between my nose and the lens. The modification to deal with that is reversible - I hot-glued some strips of old inner tube to the bridge pads, making the glasses sit a tiny bit higher and opening a little gap.

I also drilled 3 holes (⌀2 mm) in the bridge.  I may enlarge them to 3 mm.

[image: modified sunglasses]

A warm afternoon test ride including using the aero bars and putting some effort in showed that they fit just as well, don't slide down, and vision through the top of the lenses is better.  I could feel air flowing behind the lenses where I couldn't on Monday, though still not as much  as I'd get with a less close-fitting pair.

Comment: I still need to test in cooler conditions, and may put anti-fog stuff on just one side at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with fogging up glasses lies with the shape of the glasses AND the shape of the rider's head. Some combinations are simply incompatible.

Since you can't change your head, try with a different pair of glasses. Also, some glasses have small ventilation holes at the top of the screen. Or you might get replacement screens that have these.

Comment: Your point is a good one, however these are the most comfortable pair I've had, as well as being one of the best for vision (as I seem to use the very top of the lens, and the edge gets in the way if they slide down).  Similar ones aren't available to try on (in fact nothing is available to try on at the moment) and I'm not going to buy stuff at random. You get a +1 for the mention of small vent holes - that's assured me that such a thing is reasonable.